# What can two threads/objects do in a collection of objects safely in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

So before I start working on a multi threaded program that should interact with multiple objects that are part of a collection.... I want to gain a clear understanding of the concepts involved...

My main concerns are things like deadlocks and such.

Say I have a collection of objects defined like so...

```
vector<MyObjects> m_objects;
```

Imagine it being populated with between 100-500 objects.
Now imagine that each of these objects needs to have the ability to communicate with all the other objects at some point. In english, they need to be able to both read and write to all the other objects safely...

I know that in order to write to an object it needs to be locked... But can one object read from another object safely without extra functionality? If so, can an object read from a locked object that is being written to? (My first guess to that last question is no, as that would not make sense)

If anyone has some easily understandable articles/reads on the subject I would love to dive into that for a bit...

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. "Now imagine... .. the other objecs at some point"... what other objects? The other objects in Vector?

Comment: Yes the other objects in the vector.

Comment: The question would be - does vector ever change. If vector does not change, vector itself need not be protected. In general, multiple reads are safe, read/write and multiple writes aren't safe. You also have the issue of "false sharing", where objects can live in close proximity of each other in cache, causing unnecessary cache thrashing.

Comment: OK, can the vector itself be modified? Can it grow in size, can items be removed at runtime, etc.

Comment: The contents of the vector would constantly be changing, as well additions and removal of objects in the vector would be happening.

Comment: I'd suggest you google some thread-safe data storage and access patterns. Also, depending on what types of data you need to read/write to and which C++ features your compiler supports, you might want to look into using std::atomic variables where possible to reduce the mutex/semaphore hassle in your code.

Comment: One object can only read from another object safely if you can somehow guarantee that during that read, the other object will not get modified or destroyed by another thread.  If other threads are adding objects to the vector, this can be particularly difficult to guarantee, since if the vector needs to resize its array larger it will allocate a new array, copy all of the objects in its existing array over to the new array, and then delete the old array.  The easiest way to guarantee safety is to have a lock and make sure to lock it before reading/writing the array or anything inside it.

Comment: @Ricky, It would be very difficult to comment if one does not know how objects inter-relate with each other. Obviously one would not be allowed to modify the vector itself while objects are being accessed. I would first code for correctness, and optimize for efficiency later. You've mentioned two problems - (1) The vector can be modified and (2) objects in the vector relate to each other (this is my understanding). The vector may never be modified (especially size modification), while objects inside the vector relate to instances of objects inside the vector.

Comment: ...This model (mentioned here above) would require indirection concerning the items in the vector (therefore pointers would need to be used...). Indirection would mean that objects can relate to each other, as it would not matter if iterators of the vector are invalidated.

Comment: They don't neccessarly relate to each other... One object is not part of another object. They simple interact with each other...

For example if you imagine the objects as Boxers....
Boxer1 can hit Boxer2 which would lower his health.
Boxer1 can get Boxer1's name, and skill level.
Boxer 2 can do the same thing as Boxer1, to Boxer1 or any other Boxer...

Answer (score 0):

You have to lock shared resources within an object.  Each objects should keep its on state within them, if that states are not part of shared resources of system you don't need to lock them.

Answer (score 0):

The safest solution would be to lock the whole vector, so only one thread at a time can modify the vector and the objects it contains. However, the question is, if there would still be a point in multithreading then...

Trying to protect every object in the vector with its own lock could easily lead to circular dependencies and is potentially dangerous.

Imagine following scenario, using your Boxer metaphor from the comments above:

Boxer1 tries to hit Boxer2. If the impact of the punch is dependent on Boxer1's current health level, you would have to lock Boxer1 first, because you don't want anyone to change his health while performing the punch operation. At the same time, you would have to lock Boxer2, because you don't want anyone to increase his health during Boxer1's punch (maybe Boxer1 would have knocked Boxer2 out...).

Now if Boxer2 tries to hit Boxer2 simultaneously tries to hit Boxer1, you would also lock Boxer2 first and then Boxer1.

So if both of the threads performing operations on your boxers get to the part where they lock their own boxer at the same time, they would be waiting forever to lock the other boxer and you would have a deadlock.

To prevent such deadlocks, you would have to work out some kind of locking hierarchy.